# How to insert an item into a key/value pair object?

Tags: c#, insert, list

I just need to be able to insert a key/value pair into an object at a specific position. I'm currently working with a Hashtable which, of course, doesn't allow for this functionality. What would be the best approach?

UPDATE: Also, I do need the ability to lookup by the key.

For example (oversimplified and pseudocoded but should convey the point):

```
// existing Hashtable
myHashtable.Add("somekey1", "somevalue1");
myHashtable.Add("somekey2", "somevalue2");
myHashtable.Add("somekey3", "somevalue3");

// Some other object that will allow me to insert a new key/value pair.
// Assume that this object has been populated with the above key/value pairs.
oSomeObject.Insert("newfirstkey","newfirstvalue");
```

Answer (score 154, accepted):

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> kvpList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Key1", "Value1"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Key2", "Value2"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Key3", "Value3"),
};

kvpList.Insert(0, new KeyValuePair<string, string>("New Key 1", "New Value 1"));
```

Using this code:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in kvpList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Key: {0} Value: {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
}
```

the expected output should be:

```
Key: New Key 1 Value: New Value 1
Key: Key 1 Value: Value 1
Key: Key 2 Value: Value 2
Key: Key 3 Value: Value 3
```

The same will work with a KeyValuePair or whatever other type you want to use..

**Edit -**

To lookup by the key, you can do the following:

```
var result = stringList.Where(s => s == "Lookup");
```

You could do this with a KeyValuePair by doing the following:

```
var result = kvpList.Where (kvp => kvp.Value == "Lookup");
```

Comment: Apologies, I just updated to clarify that I need the ability to lookup by the key.

Comment: @Clay Note that looking a value up by the key in the `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` is O(n), instead of O(1).  In other words, for large sizes, the performance will be worse looking up an item by the key when using the list.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks, I will be dealing with smaller sizes so this should work well.

@Ian Thank you for the edits, I actually just realized that your initial response didn't allow for true key/value pairing. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks this helped me!

Comment: This is exaclty what I'm looking for too. Unfortunately I've tried it but not possible to use the where-clause on the kvpList as given by the example. Anything changed that much until 4.61?

Comment: In the same way you can add a new KeyValuePair to a List. Very helpful answer.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe the [OrderedDictonary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary_members.aspx) will help you out.

Answer (score 5):

Do you need to look up objects by the key?  If not, consider using `List<Tuple<string, string>>` or `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` if you're not using .NET 4.

Comment: Yes, I do need to look up by key.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) (so long as each key is unique).

**EDIT:** Sorry, realised you wanted to add it to a specific position. My bad. You could use a [SortedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c(v=VS.100).aspx) but this still won't let you insert.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an [OrderedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx), but I would question why you would want to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Use a linked list. It was designed for this exact situation.
If you still need the dictionary O(1) lookups, use both a dictionary and a linked list.

Answer (score 1):

Hashtables are not inherently sorted, your best bet is to use another structure such as a SortedList or an ArrayList

Comment: The Hashtable is pre-existing code that I would really prefer not to change at this time.